# How to get data order by Sort Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-order-by

I have three tables called `Service` , `Location` and `SeriveLocation`.

`Service` Table data as follows

```
ServiceID       Service     SortValue
1           Customer call       5
2               Reload          2
3           Internet setting    3
4               E care          7
5               Anti call       4
6               MMS             1
7            settings           6
```

And `SeriveLocation` Table data as follows

```
FkLcoationID    FkServiceID   SortValue
001                 1           2
002                 1           1
003                 1           2
004                 1           NULL
005                 1           4
001                 2           3
002                 2           4
003                 2           4
004                 2           NULL
005                 2           1
001                 3           4
002                 3           2
003                 3           3
004                 3           NULL
005                 3           3
001                 4           1
002                 4           3
003                 4           1
004                 4           NULL
005                 4           2
```

Now I need to get particular location data with Its `service`s and `serviceID`s order by `SeriveLocation` table's `sortValue`. If `SeriveLocation`'s table `sortValue` is `NULL` I need to get an order of services using `Service` table's `SortValue`

My expected output is when `locationId` = `001`

[image]

When `LocationId` = `004` (according mapping table, there is no sortVlaue for location 004, therefor its sort order need to take from service table)

[image]

How can I do this?

I tried this for, when Sortvalue is Null

```
select sm.FkBranchId,sm.FkServiceId,s.ServiceName from SeriveLocation sm
INNER JOIN Service s ON s.ServiceID = sm.FkServiceId
where sm.FkLocationId = 004 
order by s.SortValue
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Looks like you just need a `JOIN` and an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: @Larnu I'm new to this sir,can u please help me

Comment: Have a look at the syntax for `JOIN` and `ORDER BY`. The best way to learn is by research and trying; and a `JOIN` is a fundamental of SQL so you *need* to learn about them. If you fail, edit your attempt(s) in so we can explain where you went wrong.

Comment: [Using the SQL-92 INNER JOIN syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#f-using-the-sql-92-inner-join-syntax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a `left join` and `coalesce()`:

```
select s.Service, sl.ServiceId,
       coalesce(sl.SortValue, s.SortValue)
from ServiceLocation sl left join
     Service s
     on sl.ServiceId = s.ServiceId
where sl.FkLocationId  = ?
order by coalesce(sl.SortValue, s.SortValue);
```

Comment: What happens inside coalesce ? When  SeriveLocation table sortvalue is empty..is it take sort order from service table? I'm I correct

Comment: and where shoul I add where condion ? as example when `FkLocationId = 004 ` ??

Comment: @Adam . . . `COALESCE()` returns the first non-`NULL` value.